# Get the loaded LESS file and compile it on demand

Tags: less

I'm trying to compile a small `LESS` portion of code and mixing it with a bigger one already compiled in the page.

I thought there was some way to reuse the compiled less or maybe load it again, mix it with the newer code and then compile it mixed in the page.

I thought to load it in some way like the example below:

```less
var runtime_less = '@bg:red; .selector { background-color:@bg; }';
var library_less = '@var:bla bla bla...';

var library_parser = new(less.Parser)({
    paths: ['.', './lib'], // Specify search paths for @import directives
    filename: 'css/full_library.less' // Specify a filename, for better error messages
});

frontsize_parser.parse('', function (e, tree) {
    library_less = tree;
});

var runtime_parser = new(less.Parser)({});
runtime_parser.parse(library_less, function (e, tree) {
    // this should be inside some load event
    $("#container-style").text(library_less.toCSS() + ' ' + tree.toCSS());
});
```

Does exist some way to get the current page loaded LESS file and treat it in some way?

Or does exist some way to load `LESS` files and then mix the `LESS` data with a string with additional `LESS` code?

Answer (score 0):

with t.less containing:

```
@color: lightgreen;
```

You can use the following code:

```
<link type="text/css" href="t.less" rel="stylesheet/less">
<script>

less = { 
    env: "development"
};
</script>  
<script src="/less.js/dist/less.js"></script>
<script>
var tmp = less.parse;
less.parse = function(input,option,callback) {
tmp(input + ' h1 {color:@color;}',option,callback);
}
less.refreshStyles();   
</script>
```